# Adding a UIBarButtonItem programmatically

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, swift5

I'm trying to add a UIBarButtonItem programmatically.

```
let navigation = UINavigationController()
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "LogIn", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(logInPressed))
navigation.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

And also made a selector function for testing.

```
@objc func logInPressed() {
   print("go to login")
}
```

Unfortunately that does not work - bar button is not visible on navigation bar in simulator.

Checked with a breakpoint, rightBarButtonItem exists.

Probably issue can be caused by creating bar button from app coordinator, not from child VC.

Could please anyone help to troubleshoot this issue? 
[Simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsqkx.png)

Comment: Could you please expand on your question and explain what you are having trouble with?

Comment: @LennartHase I'm having a problem with having right navigation bar visible on a navigation bar in simulator.

Comment: Where are you showing this UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding UIBarButtonItem to a new instance of NavigationController. so it will not appear there.

so in your view controller which you want to handle right navigation bar , under one of these methods:
 `override func viewDidLoad()` 
or
 `override func viewWillAppear`

add:

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "LogIn", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(logInPressed))

self.navigationController?.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(rightBarButton, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by creating bar button not from child VC, but coordinator.

Bar buttons are stored in `navigationItem` property of `UIViewController`.